# CSS: 2X2 grid becomes 4X1 on expanding window

Tags: html, css

Currently, my code looks fine if my window is small. But as I expand my window, the second row of boxes moves up to the first, maintaining a 5px margin. I tried display: inline-block originally, but this also exhibited the same problem. Doing float:right on the second row didn't help either.

```
.Top {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    left: 25%;
    height: 301px; 
    width: 301px;
    margin: 5px; 
    background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg);
    line-height: 200px;   
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px white;
    border-top: 1px white;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}

.Bottom {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    left: 25%;
    height: 301px; 
    width: 301px;
    margin: 5px; 
    background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg);
    line-height: 200px;   
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px white;
    border-top: 1px white;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class = "Top">
            <h6>BOX 1</h6>
               <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                   <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "Top">
           <h6>BOX 2</h6>
                <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "Bottom">
           <h6>Box 3</h6>
                <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "Bottom">
           <h6>Box 4</h6>
                <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>

     </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: youre specifying a fixed width on your elements (`width: 301px;`), try using percentages, or a container that houses them that doesnt go wider than youd like using `max-width`

Comment: thank you - the later worked

Answer (score 0):

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/w06mr42y/

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            <div class = "Top">
                <h6>BOX 1</h6>
                   <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                       <a href = "#">from</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class = "Top">
               <h6>BOX 2</h6>
                    <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                    <a href = "#">from</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class = "Bottom">
               <h6>Box 3</h6>
                    <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                    <a href = "#">from</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class = "Bottom">
               <h6>Box 4</h6>
                    <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                    <a href = "#">from</a></p>
            </div>

         </div>
      </div>
.clearfix  {
  clear: both;
}

.Top {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height: 301px; 
    width: 301px;
    margin: 5px; 
    background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg);
    line-height: 200px;   
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px white;
    border-top: 1px white;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}

.Bottom {
    position:relative;
    height: 301px; 
    float: left;
    width: 301px;
    margin: 5px; 
    background-image: url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg);
    line-height: 200px;   
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px white;
    border-top: 1px white;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}
```

OR https://jsfiddle.net/w06mr42y/1/